# Bounding $|f'(0)|$ for a complex function $f$

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that $f$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{D}$ and that
$$|f(z)| < 1, \quad |z| < 1.$$
Given that $f(0) = 1/2$, I would like to obtain a bound on $|f'(0)|$.

My first instinct is to somehow use the Schwarz lemma, but the condition that $f(0) = 0 $ is not satisfied, which makes me think I must somehow modify $f$ (conformal map maybe?$ before applying the lemma, or is this the wrong approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|z|<1$, let$$g(z)=\frac{f(z)-1/2}{1-f(z)/2}.$$Then $g(0)=0$. On the other hand, $g=\varphi\circ f$, with$$\varphi(z)=\frac{z-1/2}{1-z/2}.$$Then, by the Schwarz lemma, $|g'(0)|\leqslant1$. But$$g'(0)=\varphi'(f(0))f'(0)=\varphi'\left(\frac12\right)f'(0)=\frac43f'(0).$$Therefore, $\bigl|f'(0)\bigr|\leqslant\frac34$.

Comment: Thanks! Would it have been possible to define $g$ differently, and as a result obtain a different bound? I am curious what motivated the denominator in $g(z)$.

Comment: It's a duplicate.

Comment: @CBBAM It's chosen so that it maps the open unit disk onto itself.